# Finding minimum page size to allow TLB access to overlap with tag fetch

Tags: cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, cpu-cache

Homework question, so please just nudge me in the right direction.

> Consider a system with physically-addressed caches, and assume that 40-bit virtual addresses and 32-bit physical addresses are used, and the memory is byte-addressable.  Further assume that the cache is 4-way set-associative, the cache line size is 64 Bytes and the total size of the cache is 64 KBytes.
>
> What should be the minimum page size in this system to allow for the overlap of the TLB access and the cache access?

I've been stuck on this question and have no idea how to even begin. Can someone give me a hint towards finding the solution?

Comment: Here is what you have to do: 1- Calculate the number of sets in the cache. 2- Partition a physical address into a cache line offset field, a cache set index field, and a cache line tag field. 3- Do the same for a virtual address. 4- Determine the minimum page size such that the cache set index would not require virtual-to-physical translation (because the values of the bits would remain the same), which would enable parallel access.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most important piece of information in the question is

> overlap of the TLB access and the cache access

This means, we access the Cache at the same time we access the TLB. In practice, what we really do is, we index the cache with the index bits from the virtual address and by the time we have located the entry in the cache, we will have the data (physical address) from the TLB. Then we can do the tag comparison with physical address. In other words cache acts as a Virtually indexed, Physically tagged (VIPT) cache.

Even though the scheme sounds efficient, the thing to lookout is, number of bits used to index the cache, cannot be higher than the number of bits needed to represent the page size. Simply, size of a page can put an upper limit on the number of cache entries.

Now coming back to your question,

its a 64KBytes cache with 4 way set assoc. and cacheline of 64Bytes.

```
Number of cachelines = (64KBytes/4)/64Bytes = 2^8 cachelines
```

That means if a page is 256Bytes or bigger, we can use this mechanism. If a page is smaller than 256 Bytes, then we cannot assume the index bits of the virtual address and the physical address are going to be the same.

> What should be the minimum page size in this system to allow for the
>   overlap of the TLB access and the cache access?

```
256Bytes
```

Comment: VIPT caches in general don't *require* that all the index bits come from below the page offset.  That requirement is only if you want it to have the same lack of homonym/synonym aliasing as a PIPT cache, which is what the question specifies (physically-addressed cache).  VIPT only as a speed trick for PIPT is a special case of VIPT in general.  You can also have page-coloring to work around aliasing: [Virtually indexed physically tagged cache Synonym](//stackoverflow.com/q/46588219).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for this, didn't know that. If I understand correctly, in a 4K page scenario (12 bits) if I want to have 13 bits of cache index, I can still use VIPT, provided OS make sure that 13th bit of PA = 13th bit of VA

Comment: Yup, otherwise the OS has to flush the cache on page-table changes.  IDK if you'd really call VIPT with page-coloring a physically-addressed cache, although with software cooperation it behaves that way and avoids any extra flushing. Some early CPUs used VIVT caches, or (even simpler) direct-mapped virtual caches where the OS did just have to flush caches on context switches or changes to page tables.  But as caches have grown larger and more valuable, that's not an attractive option even for L1d.

Comment: @PeterCordes But this answer is incorrect. With 256-byte pages, some (in fact, most) of the index bits would require translation to access a PIPT cache.

Comment: @HadiBrais: good catch, I didn't check the math or reasoning in the rest of the answer.  I was just commenting on the first paragraph (which does explain the right concept, that all the index bits come from below the page offset and translate for free.)

Comment: @HadiBrais what am I missing? Why would index bits needs translation? In my understanding, only the remainder of the virtual address needs translating as the virtual and physical page sizes are same

Comment: @IsuruH: You may have forgotten the offset-within-cacheline bits of the address.  You calculate 2^8 = 256 cache lines so you need 8 index bits, but then you say that 256 * 1 byte is a large enough page size for 8 index bits to be below the page offset.  But the 6 offset-within-line bits have to be below that, so you actually need a 8+6 = 14 bits for the offset-within-page.

Comment: The formula in [Minimum associativity for a PIPT L1 cache to also be VIPT, accessing a set without translating the index to physical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59279049) `min associativity = cache size / page size` can be solved for `min page size = cache size / associativity`